# How to automatically test TSQL?

Tags: automated-testing, tools, sql

I am not a tester, but SQL Developer. Can you advise me about more propper (in your opinion) way to make automatic testing of TSQL. I use SQL 2008R2 and SQL2012.

I see that there is only [one](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/803/database-code-unit-testing-tips) or [two](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3514/ms-sql-server-sql-test-automation) such question, but they are old ('09 and '12). So is there some more advanced and newer way to make that?

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward option seems to be using Microsoft Visual Studio. See [How to: Create a Test Project for Database Unit Testing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833171(v=vs.100).aspx) for details.

If you looking for a free open source standalone tool an alternative solution can be [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/). It provides [JDBC Request Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) so you will be able to execute arbitrary TSQL queries and define pass/fail criteria using [Assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions). JMeter isn't shipped with any JDBC libraries so you'll have to download i.e. [Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt484311(v=sql.110).aspx) or [jTDS JDBC Driver](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) and put it somewhere in JMeter's classpath ("lib" folder of your JMeter installation).

Moreover, JMeter is designed for load testing so you'll be able either to speed up your tests by running them in parallel or even test your SQL server instance performance. See [Building a Database Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html) and [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) articles for more detailed information.